# Cut variable into multiple Strings

Tags: string, powershell, variables, powershell-4.0

I want to write a script that renames all NICs on a Server 2012 R2.
Currently it looks like this with each one:

```
$NIC = Get-WMIObject -Class Win32_NetworkAdapter -Filter "NetconnectionID='Embedded LOM 1 Port 1'"
$NIC.NetconnectionID = 'Physical 1'
$NIC.Put()
```

Now I want to use this for different Servers and therefore I have to get the `NetconnectionID` from a variable.

So far I have put the NICs into a variable:

```
$NICS = Get-NetAdapter | select name
```

Now when just issuing the command `$NICS` it shows the list of names, but since I want to rename however many of NICs I have individually I have to break the variable down into different strings. It would be awesome if it would even count the amount and then implement my script with an `if` statement or `foreach`!

But for now I would be happy with a solution to rename a specific amount (in my case it's four).

Comment: well, which four of the nic's you are getting do you want to rename? how are you going to identify those?

Comment: Is it only the `LOM` ports you want to rename? If not, what is the renaming scheme/mapping?

Comment: @4c74356b41 I want to rename all four of them. The example I gave above was only one of four parts. I can already rename all four of them by script, but I have to adjust the NetconnectionID for every server I use the script for.
(at) Mathias Yes only the LOM ports, but in other cases they might be called differently - this is where my problem arises.

Answer (score 0):

```
$NICS = Get-NetAdapter | select name

for ($i = 0; $i -lt $NICS.Count; $i++) {
    Write-Host (($NICS[$i]) -replace("@{name=","") -replace("}",""))
}
```

That is a good starting point I think.

Answer (score 0):

Use foreach for that:

```
$NICS = Get-NetAdapter | select name
foreach ($n in $nics)
{
   write-host  "Nick name " $n.name
}
```